# Unity object having weird interaction with light

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, light

I'm currently doing a scene where light travels through a window into a completely dark room. I want the light to shine on a blood shatter, but when I turn on my light, the complete texture shows, not only what is touched by the light. Example:
[image]

I've tried messing around with the shader and the light, but without prevail.

EDIT1: Image of my blood splatter GameObject settings.
[image]

Comment: Is your blood 2d-object or 3d-object?

Comment: @vmchar The blood is 3d =)

Comment: Is the blood object set to receive shadows?

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, I'll add an image of by blood settings